# None of the browsers are able to be launched and getting java.lang.NullPointerException and process exit with -1

Tags: java, junit, cross-browser, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

This is my Hook class.

```
public class Hooks {


    public String browser;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    //IE, Chrome, Opera working |||  firefox ~working
    @Before
    public void beforeEach() throws IOException {

        browser = System.getenv("BROWSER");
        if (browser == null) {
            browser = "ie";
        }
        System.out.println("Browser selected is " + browser);

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {

            File file = new File("C:/Program Files/SeleniumDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("opera")) {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            File file = new File("C:/Program Files/SeleniumDrivers/operadriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);

        } else{
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              }
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }


    @After
    public void close() {


        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

I am using Selenium Junit with cucumber.
I have implemented the code for IE, firefox, chrome, opera.
I am unable to launch the browsers and getting java null pointer exception.
And no other error information in the console.

The below is my java class for login steps. Any clue please?

```
public class LoginSteps {

    public WebDriver driverLaunch;
    public String landingURL = "https://www.periscopix.com";

    public LoginSteps() {
        driverLaunch = Hooks.driver;
    }

    @Given("^I am on company landing page$")
    public void I_am_on_company_landing_page() throws Throwable {
        driverLaunch.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        driverLaunch.close();
    }

    @Given("^I wait for some time$")
    public void I_wait_for_some_time() throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @When("^Then the page loads succesfully$")
    public void Then_the_page_loads_succesfully() throws Throwable {
        assertEquals(driverLaunch.getCurrentUrl(), landingURL);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're getting a null pointer exception because you're setting driverLaunch to a static variable that has not been instantiated yet.  just remove driverLaunch and access driver directly.

Answer (score 0):

Extend ^Hooks^ in your ^LoginSteps^ and use the static driver instance of ^Hooks^. Remove the ^driverLaunch^ variable.